# c# how to use a template in a get property?

Tags: c#, templates, properties, get

I have some problem to use a template in a get property in c#. The following class has no problem:

```
public class test
{
    public T GetDefault<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

But i would like to use get property and then there is a error

> unexpected use of generic name

the code is following:

```
public class test
{
    public T Default<T> => default<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think current C# version support such syntax sugar. But you can get similar behavior like this:

```
public static class test<T>
{
    public static T Default => default(T);
}
```

And then use it:

```
var value = test<int>.Default;
```

Actually, if you strugling between two, I would reccomend to stay at methods:

```
public static class test
{
    public static T GetDefault<T>() => default(T);
}
```

Benefit is that you can put different extensions in same test class, on different types.

Answer (score 2):

There are no generic properties in C# so far. You can find details [here](https://newcome.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/why-arent-there-generic-properties-in-c/) and [here](https://secondboyet.com/Articles/GenericProperties.html):

> We must reserve space for the backing store for the generic property
>   [...]. But we don't know how much to reserve.
>   Even if the compiler had read and understood every possible use of the
>   generic.

MSDN states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction):

> Properties are a natural extension of fields. Both are named members
>   with associated types.

They *must* have an associated type at compile-time.